# Enum value as function parameter mapped to specific return type

Tags: typescript

I have created a small example of a problem I'm experiencing. I want the `get` function to take a enum parameter, and have the return value of the function be dependant on that enum value. I'm trying to map the enum value to it's type in a mapped type, but I'm not having any luck.

The code below doesn't work - it seems like it believes the mapping type to be a union type.

```js
type T1 = { name: string }
type T2 = { age: number }
enum Type { TypeOne, TypeTwo }

const get = <T extends Type>(type: T): {
    [Type.TypeOne]: T1
    [Type.TypeTwo]: T2
}[T] => type === Type.TypeOne ? { name: 'Brian' } : { age: 42 }
```

I get the error message on the last line:

```
Type '{ name: string; } | { age: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ 0: T1; 1: T2; }[T]'.
  Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ 0: T1; 1: T2; }[T]'.
    Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T1 & T2'.
      Property 'age' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' but required in type 'T2'.ts(2322)
```

[Fiddle link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3lAdgQwLYQFxQDOwATgJboDmUAvgFCiSwBMSqUml%20GArtgEYQStOhHR9Y4aGhhSA8uggAaSZBgB3APYi6AY03piULsDYAeGFAgAPYGIAmhVRAB8ACkbcYASgIo6UIFQANqykAB0YRAKEAC6BPABQaFSkVIamvEsdDShsUguUJ5IiMhRaZAxUAD87Fi4BADkAELkmOiNtFB%20HFwEACys9EA)

Any suggestions?

Comment: The way you're doing it would need a TS feature requested at [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).  In its absence you can refactor so that the generic indexed access is accomplished by an actual object index, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wR745N).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ahh yeah, that seems to address the question fully. A person in the GitHub issues has a very similar example to mine. Write up an answer, and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript currently can't use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to affect [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) *type parameters*.  So while checking `type === Type.TypeOne` will have an effect on the apparent type of `type`, the generic type parameter `T` will stubbornly remain unaffected.

It might seem "obvious" that checking `type === Type.TypeOne` should narrow `T` from `T extends Type` to `T extends Type.TypeOne`, but in general this would be incorrect.  After all, `T` *might* be the full [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `Type`.  For a call signature like `<T extends Type>(type1: T, type2: T) => void`, it would be dangerous to assume that checking `type1 === Type.TypeOne` would mean that `type2 === Type.TypeOne`.  So some other approach is necessary, possibly as described in the open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).  But for now, nothing like this is implemented.

---

Until and unless support for that is added, the way I'd approach implementing a generic function that returns an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) is to actually index into an appropriately-typed object with the appropriate index.  For your example that could look like:

```
const get = <T extends Type>(type: T): {
    [Type.TypeOne]: T1
    [Type.TypeTwo]: T2
}[T] => ({
    [Type.TypeOne]: { name: 'Brian' },
    [Type.TypeTwo]: { age: 42 }
}[type]);
```

If you really need to, you could even write this with [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) so that the object lazily computes only the member you are accessing:

```
const get = <T extends Type>(type: T): {
    [Type.TypeOne]: T1
    [Type.TypeTwo]: T2
}[T] => ({
    get [Type.TypeOne]() { return { name: 'Brian' } },
    get [Type.TypeTwo]() { return { age: 42 } }
}[type]);
```

For the example code that wouldn't matter much, but you might want to do this if the original function has side effects or if pre-computing every possible return value is too expensive.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwgOYEtLgK4CMB0BjAewFthjV8AnQuQgM0mABUBPGAUwGUrUZHU4cTOzjAAzGIAMARgAsAKHmQ27UE2mgAvKADeoAHYBDYuwSg4kSqn3JQAXyUq1AJi27Qh5KYOZi2dpT28uz6vmpOeqwcAPL67AA04RxMAO6EQfJE+hagXpBuADxMoOwAHpAhACZwSewAfAAUyhxmTACUZjryoD2gANpR7LiDsewAuq3S3b0DKsMqqYQTLvJ2A2NadaANXb39g-Mxcct6RiZmAOQAQlaG+hf28dM9sxyH7IsnHl5msq4Oa2a4zaAG5FFkcnlXNoiiVylUaoNGkDWh1dM99nMRsdJhjXkNBp9Ws5VutNttdr08pi3tjxg02u5KOxIJhKPp3GdvNdbvd7I8MdT8e9PgymSy2Ry9J5vH9+QC+kCxqCgA)